# Moving a rectange in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

### My class

```
class head:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def move_right(self):
        self.change_x += 10
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black,(self.x, self.y, self.width, 
        self.height))
        pygame.display.update()
```

### For Movement

```
FPS = 30
clock.tick(FPS)
screen.fill(white)
snake = head(600, 300, 15, 15)
snake.draw()
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake.move_right()
```

I want it to move a rectangle i have drawn using 'pygame.draw.rect' .I tried running it making several twerks here and there but couldn't get it to move.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your infinite loop so it includes the filling of the screen as well as the drawing of the snake. Otherwise it only gets drawn once. At the end, call `pygame.display.update()`.

```
while True:
    screen.fill(white)
    snake.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake.move_right()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also note that this part of the code does something weird:

```
self.change_x += 10
self.x += self.change_x
self.y += self.change_y
```

This gets called every time you press the right key. Therefore, the value which is added to `self.x` increments with every press. This in the end leads to an increasing jump length of snake.